# Custom colors background in flutter

Tags: flutter, gradient

How can i do this king of background:
https://dribbble.com/shots/14805280-Wallet-app

I tried gradient, but is more than a simple gradient, i also tried ShaderMask with 3 containers, What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nearest result I get with simple implementation contains blurring effect and some container. There are some [issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64828) with borders of clipped blur which if it solves, it gets much more similar to your instance.

The [codepen link](https://codepen.io/papmodern/pen/poNZyej) is also available

[image]

```dart
class FancyBlurBox extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              height: 120,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                                child: Container(color: Color(0xFF7dccf3))),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Container(color: Color(0xFF695bf4))),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                                child: Container(color: Color(0xFFde536f))),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Container(color: Color(0xFFf6c37f))),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(10, 10),
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 30.0, sigmaY: 30.0),
                      child: Container(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I resolved this way:
https://codepen.io/christian-romero/pen/xxRoOYB

Comment: @cromero Awesome, thanks for sharing